# I have a Table with multiple columns. Is it possible to create a radio button in each column entry using Jface?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a Table with multiple columns.  Is it possible to create a radio button in each column entry using JFace?

I tried to use `TableEditor` with this I would only add one radio button to a column not on to all columns.  I am pretty new to JFace it would be greatly appreciated if you can guide me further on this.

[image: Example table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a radiobutton for every column/row you have in your table, except for column 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < employeeCount; i++)
{
    TableItem item; 
    Button radio; 
    TableEditor editor; 

    item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NO_FOCUS);

    item.setText(0, employees[i]); //Let's assume you have an array of employees' names

    radio = new Button(table, SWT.RADIO);
    //TODO: setup your radiobutton here (text, behavior, etc.)
    editor = new TableEditor(table);
    editor.setEditor(radio, item, 1); //1 is the column index (excellent)
    editor.layout();

    radio = new Button(table, SWT.RADIO);
    //TODO: setup your radiobutton here (text, behavior, etc.)
    editor = new TableEditor(table);
    editor.setEditor(radio, item, 2); //2 is the column index (good)
    editor.layout();

    radio = new Button(table, SWT.RADIO);
    //TODO: setup your radiobutton here (name, text, behavior, etc.)
    editor = new TableEditor(table);
    editor.setEditor(radio, item, 3); //3 is the column index (average)
    editor.layout();

    radio = new Button(table, SWT.RADIO);
    //TODO: setup your radiobutton here (text, behavior, etc.)
    editor = new TableEditor(table);
    editor.setEditor(radio, item, 4); //4 is the column index (poor)
    editor.layout();
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly put radio button, you will have to use images. Use ColumnLabelProvider for column and use getImage method.

Go through this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html). [This](http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.in/2007/01/tableviewers-and-nativelooking.html) will help you to give native look and feel of control.